# Estimation of viscosity from critical properties

Tags: plotting, data-sets

[image: O. A. Uyehara and K. M. Wastson, *Nat. Petroleum News, Tech. Section*, 36, 764(Oct. 4, 1944); revised]

The above graph represents **`reduced viscosity`** as a function of **`reduced temperature`** for several values of the **`reduced pressure`**.

---

I am writing a code which will estimate the viscosity, in the following steps :

1. Calculating **`critical viscosity`**($\mu_c$) by using the formula,

$$ \mu_c = 7.70M^{0.5}p_c^{2/3}T_c^{-1/6} $$

2. Calculating **`reduced temperature and pressure`** as,

$$ 
T_r = \frac{T}{T_c} \\ 
p_r = \frac{p}{p_c} $$

Now, from the graph at the top, estimating $\mu_r$ by using $T_r$ and $p_r$ values calculated from the previous step.

3. Finally, calculating the predicted value of $\mu$ as,

$$ \mu = \mu_r\mu_c $$

(this value of $\mu$ is unusually a good agreement with the measured value)

---

### Question: How do I feed/extract the data/equation of the plot (top) which is experimentally generated so that I can also plot/test it in my code?

P.S - All other parameters $T_c$ , $p_c$ , $T$ , $p$, $M$ will be input by the user

---

**REFERED** : O. A. Uyehara and K. M. Wastson, *Nat. Petroleum News, Tech. Section*, 36, 764(Oct. 4, 1944); revised | Transport Phenomena, 2nd edition, R. Byron Bird, Warren E. Stewart, Edwin N. Lightfoot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Plot Digitizer](http://plotdigitizer.sourceforge.net/) and extract the data points in your image graph as a xml file and then you can parse it by using Python. It's pretty straightforward. You need to import the image of your graph into the software. Then calibrate the X and Y axes by specifying the $x_{min}$, $x_{max}$, $y_{min}$, and $y_{max}$ which are the min and max of X and Y axes. Note that if X or Y axis is in logarithmic scale, you can specify it in the software during calibration. Finally you just manually touch the points in your graph and software would save the X and Y of points for you and you can easily import it as xml file and you can parse this xml file in Python or even in Microsoft Excel or LibreOffice.

Comment: Apologies for commenting after an eternity! 
Thank you that worked smoothly

Answer (score 0):

Dear
you can return to the reference "Courtsey of Hougen and Watson "
"Chem. Process Principle"
for more accurate calculation of reduced volume and reduced pressure at reduced temp.
and the the figure content all required data.
Best Regards
Dr. Kafaa Alani